# GNU GSL BLAS library, undefined symbols

Tags: c, xcode, macos, linker, gsl

Is there anyone that can give me a simple run down of how to install the GSL library so that it'll work with XCode (5.1) on a Mac (Mavericks, 10.9)? I keep getting this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_gsl_matrix_add", referenced from:
  _myProject in main.o
```

I initially installed GSL 1.16 in /Library/gsl-1.16
I did the whole ./configure, make, and make install

THINGS I HAVE TRIED TO FIX THIS:

1) Going to "Build Settings" in XCode and adding "/Library/gsl-1.16"
to both the library and header search paths

2) Creating a symbolic link from the ...usr/include path (... being the SDK (MacOSX 10.9) location XCode is using) to the Library path.

3) Adding "-lgsl" to the "Arguments passed on Launch" section of my project's scheme

4) Adding "-Wall -I/Library/include" to the "Arguments passed on Launch" section of my project's scheme

Nothing has worked. Xcode reports that it can *find* the headers, but it can't reference the methods associated with the header files. Truly interesting. I have no idea, I've done everything I can think of and Google.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it is difficult to locate whether you set the build settings correctly. I installed GSL using macports and not sure how it would be like if installed directly from source. But I believe you need to figure out where the `make install` installs the GSL library and header to, since typically they are installed into different paths, which are not the path you run `make install`.

And since typically `make install` will install headers to `/usr/local/include` and libraries to `/usr/local/lib`, I guess it is possible that you set the wrong path to the libraries. Assume you figured out that your GSL library is in `/usr/local/lib` (and typically they should), you just need to do one of the two things (not both):

1. Change Library search path to `/usr/local/lib`. (and header search path to `/usr/local/include` as you did)
2. Change compiler arguments to `-Wall -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib`. (last two arguments start with capital i and capital L).

Here is the procedure how I install GSL using macports and set up it in Xcode to run a matrix addition:

1. Install macports if you haven't done it. Refer to https://www.macports.org/install.php .
2. In terminal, type `sudo port install gsl` and have several cups of coffee.
3. By default, macports installs librarys to `/opt/local/lib` and headers to `/opt/local/include`. So after you create a C++ project in Xcode, go to build settings, add the three settings below:

   - Library search paths: `/opt/local/lib`
   - Header search paths: `/opt/local/include`
   - Other linker flags: `-lgsl` (depending on what you want to do, you may also need to add `-lgsl -lgslcblas` and other flags.)
4. Now it is up and running. Include `<gsl/gsl_matrix.h>` and `gsl_matrix` is ready to use.